# Ionic Google Play few compatible devices

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, google-play

I have an Ionic (Angular) application published on Google Play, however it has 2700 compatible devices and I am having problems, because several users are unable to install or update it anymore.

I looked in forums and on the Google Play Console support page, and the only things I found about it is talking about the `Minimum SDK Target` and settings in the `AndroidManifest.xml` for functions and mandatory sensors. However, my app does not have any mandatory functions or sensors configured in the `AndroidManifest.xml` and my `Minimum SDK Target` is 19 (4.4).

Has anyone been through this and knows how to solve it? Because I have other apps using Ionic as well and React Native that compatible devices reach 17 thousand

Comment: what version of cordova-android are you using ? Have you set `minSdkVersion` and `android-targetSdkVersion` on your config.xml file ?

Comment: @saperlipopette Yes, `minSdkVersion` is set to `19` and `android-targetSdkVersion` to `29`